# Will refresh token expire once 2FA is enabled

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

We generated a refresh token with the following C# code snippet:

```cs
public IActionResult GetGoogleToken()
{
    UserCredential credentials = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        new ClientSecrets()
        {
            ClientId = "CLIENT_ID",
            ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET"
        },
        new string[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new NullDataStore()).Result;

    return Json(credentials.Token.RefreshToken);
}
```

Since then, we have been using it to fetch emails using Gmail API:

```cs
private async Task<GmailService> GetGmailService()
{
    UserCredential credentials = new UserCredential(
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets()
                {
                    ClientId = "CLIENT_ID",
                    ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET"
                }
            }),
        "user",
        REFRESH_TOKEN
    );
    
    if (credentials.Token.IsExpired(SystemClock.Default))
    {
        if (!await credentials.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None))
        {
            throw new Exception("Token could not be refreshed");
        }
    }

    return new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
        ApplicationName = "APP",
    });
}
```

My question is: Will the refresh token expire once we enable 2FA on the account? Is this behavior documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration), that is not a valid reason for the refresh token to expire. It will expire if in case during the 2FA enabling process the user changes password and the refresh token has gmail scopes.

Comment: Excuse me can you paste the exact section of that page that states that it will expire if you enable 2fA im not seeing anything related to that.

Comment: @DaImTo I cannot paste that because it does not exists and I never mention such thing.

Comment: It will expire if in case during the 2FA enabling process <--- nothing in the docs says that.   You do not need to change your password when enabling 2fa.

Comment: @DaImTo you are right... 99% of the time, it won't happen. However, when enabling 2FA you are required to enter your password, therefore there are only 2 scenarios in which password change would be required. 1. The organization policy mandates a password change or 2. The user forgot the password. I know these are extreme cases, but it could happen that is why I specified.. "If in case".  Anyways, perhpas I am wrong but that is my experience so far.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing authorization and authentication.

The code you are using requests that the user authorize your application to access their gmail data.

This has nothing to do with authentication or signin.  Authorization is not login.

2fa login is required by open id connect and signin.  Again this is not related to your gmail consent.  So no the user enabling 2fa will not effect your refresh token.

While for the most part even the user changing their password will not effect a refresh token.  Gmail api scopes are a little different the refresh token will expire if the user changes their password.